# How to reduce a nut from 32mm to 9.8mm

Tags: pipe, lamp

I am trying to build a lamp with a metal pipe (32mm thread, left side of image) and an e27 socket with a 9.6mm screw (right side of image). Any ideas on how to reduce the size of the nut? I have found some nut reducers but nothing that works for my project. I am open to any options.
Thanks!
[image: pipe and bulb]

Comment: You may either plug it or install a nipple and cap it then drill it and tap it to female thread 9.6mm, drill size approximately 75%

Comment: You also could just simply epoxy or silicone the socket base onto the elbow rim.

Comment: .... Or use multiple reducers.

Comment: Is this an actual plumbing fitting or is it from a curtain rod?  Unless it was sold as a plumbing fitting, you really don't know what type of threads you're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying Paul Logan's comment, use a close nipple [image: closed nipple] and cap [image: cap], but instead of drill and tap, just drill a hole large enough in the cap to insert the stem from the socket - tight but don't damage the threads - then take a nut that fits the stem and attach it from the inside of the cap. If it's hard to tighten it, fiddle around with some washers sized appropriately.

You could also lock it down by using 2 nuts. Put the first one on all the way next to the one holding the stem onto the socket (in your pic), insert the stem into the cap, put the 2nd nut on getting it as far as possible inside the cap - finger tight is fine - then then tighten the first one on the outside. And bobs your uncle.

Comment: It's "close nipple" rather than closed.

Comment: That or a plug that can be drilled and tapped then the nipple is not needed.

Comment: @Ed Beal - the plugs look a little harder to drill, but if you want to reduce extension and complication